# Reading 2 GB file with C# takes too much time

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have an indented text file in the following pattern:

```
cl /FoD:\jnks\complire_flags /c legacy\roxapi\fjord\Module.c

Note: including file:   d:\jnks\e\patchlevel.f

Note: including file:   d:\3_4_2_patched4\release\include\pyconfig.f
Note: including file:    C:\11.0\VC\INCLUDE\io.f
```

Using stream reader, I am able to read the above file which requires following processing.
1) Every line starting with cl and ending with c is the Parent file.
2) All files starting with Note and ending with f are child files.
3) The .f file is parent of the .f file below it if left indent increases,(space between file: and drive name) hence pyconfig.f is a parent of io.f

Using Entity framework I am writing above data in two tables of SQL server; 
Parent table (for only .c files) and Child table (for only .f files).

My big issue here is- It takes 6 hours to read the file (using stream reader) and another 6 hours to write it in the database (using entity framework).  I tried first reading the whole file and then writing it. I have also tried reading the file one Parent c file at a time and writing its info along with the child .f files.

The file size might increase in future to 5 GB so I really would appreciate help in achieving better performance.

Below is a part of my read logic:

```
while (!isEndOfFile)
{
    // Read next Line conditionally
    if (readNextLine)
    {
        if (inputFile.Peek() > -1)
        {
            line = inputFile.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            isEndOfFile = true;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // Get the name of the CPP file - Condition is that it starts with cl
    if (isCPPFile(line))
    {
        // Regular expression match to extract the CPP file name
        Match match = cppFilePathRegex.Match(line);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            cppFileName = match.Value;
            addFileDetails = true;
        }
        readNextLine = true;
    }
    // Check if meets the condition of Header starting text - "Note: including file:" and we have a parent CPP File
    else if (addFileDetails && isHeaderFile(line))
    { 
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler to tell you where the time is being taken?

Comment: You don't have to "Peek" to check for end-of-file: ReadLine returns null when you reach that, so you can check for that.

Comment: It takes 6 hours for your machine to read a 2gb file? thats lunacy.. nothing Ive done takes that long. Even on a USB drive.. something clearly is chewing your time and Im going to bet its not the actual reading.

Comment: When you comment out the "write to database" part (and leave only the "read from file" part), how quickly does it run then? In other words, is the bottleneck in the reading or in the writing?

Comment: @farina kidwai Ho much time does it take to copy the file using the explorer? If the read speed is ok you should consider to increase the buffer size of the StreamReader instance you use (unfortunately you omitted the constructor call of StreamReader)

Comment: @Rowland Thanks for the response. I have not used Profiler yet but when I re-wrote code to first read all records and then write- it took about 5 hours before the first record was written in table.

Comment: @Hans Kesling Thanks for the response- do you think removing Peek will help ? Actually I tried two ways.  First I started by reading all entries together, storing them in list [ took 5-6 hours] then I wrote to file [took again 5-6 hrs]. Second time, I tried reading one parent, its tree and writing it down. Total time taken in that case was the same as before.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the response the file cannot be opened in notepad and notepad++ , they say its too big. Visual studio takes whole 2 minutes to open it. Copying from one folder to another, the whole file hardly takes 15 seconds.

Comment: @farinakidwai - Removing Peek will not speed up things (I think) as it will be read from an internal buffer anyway. It just is less code to write.

Comment: Edited to add: Each file line requires processing to check whether it is a parent or child or internal child file. this might be slowing the program down. I tried reading the whole file at once(with characters) but memory error occurs.

Comment: What does the `cppFilePathRegex` look like?  I've run into huge bottlenecks with `Match` before.

Comment: Thanks for the response sorrell, it is as below:     Regex cppFilePathRegex = new Regex(@"[^\/ ]+.cpp");

Answer (score 1):

1) Go and read [why GNU grep is fast?](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html). It gives a number of hints on how to process fast input text files, specifically looking for patterns.

2) Use [SQlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) to transfer the data into SQL Server. EF is definitely not an appropriate solution for bulk import.

But, if I was you, I would do a `del /q /s` on my entire import solution and start from scratch using [SQL Server Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services). SSIS is a *dedicated* solution for your task, it contains countless optimizations around file read, record access, buffering, cache access and ultimately database writes.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need to do processing on the data before I write it to the database and that is the major reason I am using C#.

Comment: SSIS can process data

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and read [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx). This should not be a *guessing* game.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the time drastically reduced (Almost 2 hours) if I split the file before I process it.
The file is in tree structure so it has to be processed line by line only but I can split it at points where a certain character occurs to signify new tree.

If I read block at new character, instead of splitting; the 2 GB file still eats up a lot of memory.

I have split the file using following power shell and will later see how I can probably call both powershell and MY C-SHARP APPLICATION (for processing and db insertion). I am still working on reducing time but please find my powershell below for reference.

// My PowerShell

```
$Path = "D:\Parser\Test\"            -- path of input file
$PathSplit = "D:\Parser\Test\Cpp\"   -- path of output
$InputFile = (Join-Path $Path "input_file.txt")       --input filename
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
$N = 1
While(($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
    If(($Line -match "^[cl].*")-and($Line -match "/Fo")) {
        $OutputFile = $matches+$N + ".txt"
        Add-Content(Join-Path $PathSplit $OutputFile) $Line
        $N++     
    }}
```

Comment: Consider splitting your code in two separate application. First application would read the file and create intermediate files of small chunks. Second application would read the intermediate chunk files and do processing and store in database. Consider using a parallel.foreach.

Comment: @Baskar thanks for the response. Yes for now I am using power-shell to split and the rest by C#, although writing to database is taking time and hence considering using multi threading as well.